# D3.horizon Chart not rendering

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to render a simple horizon chart like [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1483226) with D3.js and [Horizon.js](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/horizon) (from the venerable Jason Davies). I'm using some fitness tracker data.

Unfortunately the Mike Bostock example uses a strange json layout and does some obscure pivoting/transposing of rows to cols; making it very hard to follow.

My JSFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/Nyquist212/bwz75t7t/ renders nothing. Not even an error. My code and data looks something like this...

```
var data=[{"key":"active time","date":"05/13/2013","value":"3860.0"},{"key":"active time","date":"05/14/2013","value":"5167.0"},
{"key":"active time","date":"05/15/2013","value":"5663.0"},
{"key":"active time","date":"05/22/2013","value":"3371.0"},{"key":"distance","date":"05/13/2013","value":"5766.0"},{"key":"distance","date":"05/14/2013","value":"7472.0"},{"key":"distance","date":"05/15/2013","value":"8264.0"},{"key":"distance","date":"05/22/2013","value":"4989.0"},{"key":"steps","date":"05/13/2013","value":"7210.0"},{"key":"steps","date":"05/14/2013","value":"9481.0"},{"key":"steps","date":"05/15/2013","value":"10431.0"},{"key":"steps","date":"05/16/2013","value":"1006.0"},{"key":"steps","date":"05/22/2013","value":"6268.0"}];

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;
        d.date = parseDate(d.date); 
        d.value = Math.round(+d.value);
        });

var margin  = {top:5, right:5, bottom:5, left:5},
    height  = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom, 
    width   = 500 - margin.left - margin.right;

var chart = d3.horizon()
    .width(width)
    .height(height)
    .bands(1)
    .mode("mirror")
    .interpolate("basis");

var svg = d3.select("#body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.data([data]).call(chart);
```

Can someone help me understand what 'shape' I need to massage my json into to make this work? Is this even my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SVG isn't being added to the DOM because there is no element with `id="body"`. Line 218 needs to use tag selector `body` instead of id selector `#body`, and then the SVG will exist in the document.

Once in the document, note that the data points in the SVG are coming out NaN:

[image: NaN]

As you suspect, something is wrong with the data format. Compare yours to the data structure that the example uses:

[image: Example data]

Afaict, the example is a two dimensional array in form *[timestamp, value]* ordered by *timestamp*.

From the data manipulation method in http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1483226#index.html:

```
data = data.rate.map(function(rate, i) {
    return [Date.UTC(data.year[i], data.month[i] - 1), rate - mean];
});
```

If you format your data in the same way, it should work. Try this:

```
console.log('before: ', data);
data = data.map(function(obj, i) {
    return [obj.date.getTime(), obj.value];
}).sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a[0] > b [0] ? 1 : (a[0] == b[0] ? 0 : -1); 
});
console.log('after: ', data);
svg.data([data]).call(chart);
```

Something finally shows up - though you might want to inspect the data and make sure it's translated properly.

*NOTE: The code above flattens the 3 data key segments (`active time`, `distance`, and `steps`) into a single array. You'll probably need to split those into different series.*

Comment: Thank you Ben. BTW, what is that date format that gets returned from obj.date.getTime() ? Is that a Unix Epoch time?

Comment: Close. The unix timestamp is in seconds; Javascript's timestamp is in milliseconds. Note that `date.getTime()` and `Date.UTC()` both return this format. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime